# How to split values in a column into their own respective columns in R

Tags: r, string, dataframe, split

I have data from a multi-select question from a survey. The column contains values as a string separated by a comma. My data frame looks like this:

```
       ID       Var
1   1   3,12,14,15,16,18,20,21          
2   2   3,14,20     
3   3   3,14,16     
4   4   3,12        
5   5   3,6,14,15,17,20
```

I want to split the values into their respective columns, e.g 1s in column 1, 2s in column 2, etc. There are 21 values in total.

I've tried using `str_split_fixed` which has split the values into columns in the order the values appear:

```
str_split_fixed(df$Var, ",", 21)

      [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6] [,7] [,8] [,9] [,10] [,11] [,12] [,13] [,14]
 [1,] "3"  "12" "14" "15" "16" "18" "20" "21" ""   ""    ""    ""    ""    ""   
 [2,] "3"  "14" "20" ""   ""   ""   ""   ""   ""   ""    ""    ""    ""    ""   
 [3,] "3"  "14" "16" ""   ""   ""   ""   ""   ""   ""    ""    ""    ""    ""   
 [4,] "3"  "12" ""   ""   ""   ""   ""   ""   ""   ""    ""    ""    ""    ""   
 [5,] "3"  "6"  "14" "15" "17" "20" ""   ""   ""   ""    ""    ""    ""    ""
```

I've also tried using `cSplit` which produced something similar:

```
cSplit(df, "Var", ",")

ID    Var_01  Var_02  Var_03  Var_04  Var_05  Var_06  Var_07  Var_08  Var_09...
1   3   12  14  15  16  18  20  21  NA  
2   3   14  20  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  
3   3   14  16  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  
4   3   12  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  
5   3   6   14  15  17  20  NA  NA  NA
```

I'm want to produce something like this:

```
ID    Var_01  Var_02  Var_03  Var_04  Var_05  Var_06  Var_07  Var_08  Var_09...
1   NA  NA  3   NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  
2   NA  NA  3   NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  
3   NA  NA  3   NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  
4   NA  NA  3   NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  
5   NA  NA  3   NA  NA  6   NA  NA  NA
```

I'm still getting my head around R so any pointers would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: you want to break out the numbers into their respective integer columns?

Comment: Have you seen this existing question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68719120/how-to-convert-one-comma-split-column-into-multiple-columns-in-r

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## base R

```r
V <- strsplit(df$Var, ",") |> lapply(as.integer)
V2 <- cbind(rep(seq_along(V), times = lengths(V)), unlist(V))
m <- data.frame(matrix(NA, nrow = nrow(df), ncol = max(unlist(V))))
colnames(m) <- sprintf("Var_%02d", 1:max(unlist(V)))
m[V2] <- V2[,2]
cbind(df, m)
#   ID                    Var Var_01 Var_02 Var_03 Var_04 Var_05 Var_06 Var_07 Var_08 Var_09 Var_10 Var_11 Var_12 Var_13 Var_14 Var_15 Var_16 Var_17 Var_18 Var_19 Var_20 Var_21
# 1  1 3,12,14,15,16,18,20,21     NA     NA      3     NA     NA     NA     NA     NA     NA     NA     NA     12     NA     14     15     16     NA     18     NA     20     21
# 2  2                3,14,20     NA     NA      3     NA     NA     NA     NA     NA     NA     NA     NA     NA     NA     14     NA     NA     NA     NA     NA     20     NA
# 3  3                3,14,16     NA     NA      3     NA     NA     NA     NA     NA     NA     NA     NA     NA     NA     14     NA     16     NA     NA     NA     NA     NA
# 4  4                   3,12     NA     NA      3     NA     NA     NA     NA     NA     NA     NA     NA     12     NA     NA     NA     NA     NA     NA     NA     NA     NA
# 5  5        3,6,14,15,17,20     NA     NA      3     NA     NA      6     NA     NA     NA     NA     NA     NA     NA     14     15     NA     17     NA     NA     20     NA
```

`[`-indexing (for matrices and frames) accepts a 2-column matrix of `row,column` indexes for both extraction and assignment, which is what we're doing with `m[V2]`.

Answer (score 1):

This isn't a very common transformation as far as I've seen. you could write a helper function like

```
split_index <- function(x) {
  rows <- lapply(strsplit(x, ","), as.numeric)
  N <- max(unlist(rows))
  vals <- lapply(rows, function(v) {
    r <- numeric(N)
    r[v] <- as.character(v)
    r
  })
  vals
}
```

You can call it like

```
split_index(df$Var)
```

or if you wanted to combine into a matrix

```
split_index(df$Var) |> do.call(rbind, args=_)
```